# ASP.Net equivalent of PHP's file_get_contents ( 'php://input' );

Tags: php, asp.net

Is there an equivalent method for this in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is [Request.InputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream.aspx) not enough?

Answer (score 1):

Just as simple as the PHP one: [File.ReadAllText(path)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx)